# matplotlib add legend with multiple entries for a single scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am making a scatter plot for a dataset that looks like this:

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
labels = [1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3]

colors = np.array(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'])

plt.scatter(x, y, color=colors[labels])
```

If I call `plt.legend`, only one entry will be shown, for the entire dataset, with the first symbol. How do I create a legend with all four elements in it, displayed as if I had plotted four separate datasets?

Probably relevant: [Matplotlib histogram with multiple legend entries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43872450/2988730)
Based on: [Matplotlib, how to loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61875539/2988730)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the overall simplest solution is to delegate all the work to matplotlib. The method is described here: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#automated-legend-creation. For this simplified approach, using [`PathCollection`'s](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection) [`legend_elements`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.legend_elements) method is all you need:

```
s = plt.scatter(x, y, c=labels)
plt.legend(*s.legend_elements())
```

[image]

It's trivial to change the colormap or replace the labels with something else, like text:

```
text_labels = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
s = plt.scatter(x, y, c=labels, cmap='jet', vmin=0, vmax=4)
plt.legend(s.legend_elements()[0], text_labels)
```

[image]

If `labels` is not already a sorted array of elements in the range `[0-n)`, it can easily be obtained using [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
labels = ['b', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
text_labels, labels = np.unique(labels, return_inverse=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can plot empty lists for the set of labels:

```
for l in set(labels):
    plt.scatter([],[], color=colors[l], label=l)
plt.legend()
```

Comment: That is definitely a good idea. If I leave the original dataset unlabeled, it won't appear in the legend.

Comment: I think I found a built-in method that is arguably more efficient than this.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way of achieving the desired result. I get rid of the duplicates using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589144/4932316) solution

```
for i, j, l in zip(x, y, labels):
    plt.scatter(i, j, c=colors[l], label=l)

handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())
```

[image]

Comment: Technically yes, but I'm really trying to avoid having each point in a separate object. I feel like that wouldn't scale well.

Comment: I think I found a built-in method. I never knew matplotlib did this for you.